# How to update code using svn with crontab?

Tags: php, linux, svn, shell, cron

I am using following steps to update code on server after login to server:

```
sudo -s
<wrote password here>
cd /var/www/staging
rm -r app.old
mv app app.old
svn checkout https://example.com/projectname/trunk/app app
```

Now I created `update.sh` file in `/var/www/` with following content

```
cd /var/www/staging
rm -r app.old
mv app app.old
svn checkout https://example.com/projectname/trunk/app app
```

And I have following crontab entry to run after every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/update.sh
```

**Problem:** So cron job is working but it is only deleting the `app` folder and **not** checking out it from svn repository. But when I run `bash /var/www/update.sh` manually it works fine after `sudo -s`.

How to fix this for cron job as well. Is it related to `sudo -s` or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Whatever the user that the cron script is running at, does the user have permission to check out from SVN?

Comment: when I run `sudo -s` and then `bash /var/www/update.sh` manually, it works fine. **BUT** when cron job runs this script(update.sh) then it is not checking out code from svn.

Comment: That much I understand.  Please indicate: (1) what user is the job running as from cron (is it root or some other user); (2) does that user have permissions to checkout from svn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the job is running from cron as `root` and root user doesn't have permissions to checkout.

First, I suggest that you include details of the username/password to use with SVN - inside your script:

```
svn checkout --username USER --password PASS ttps://example.com/projectname/trunk/app app
```

Next, change the line in your crontab to this:

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/update.sh 2>&1| mail -s "Cron job execution" youremail@wherever.com
```

Then, when the job executes, any errors would be sent to you via email.  At least you'll see what is going wrong.

Comment: +1 very useful email option in crontab. Thanks. Let me figure out error now.

Comment: Can we send output of shell script to multiple email addresses ?? Thanks

Comment: @Awan yes, you can, just put multiple email addresses separated by commas (no spaces between them)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run it as a different user, then install it on that users crontab. Rather than trying to sudo over in the script.

Comment: I need to run it as a same one user. When I run the script manually, it works fine but it is not working when cron job runs it.